# Calling C function in Assembly Segfaults

Tags: c, arrays, assembly

I am trying to write an assembly program that calls a function in c that will replace certain characters in a string with a predefined character given that the currently character in the char array meets some qualification.

My c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//display *((char *) $edi)
// These functions will be implemented in assembly:
//

int strrepl(char *str, int c, int (* isinsubset) (int c) ) ;


int isvowel (int c) {

   if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u') 
      return 1 ;

   if (c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U') 
      return 1 ;

   return 0 ;
}

int main(){
    char *str1;
    int r;
// I ran my code through a debugger again, and it seems that when displaying 
// the character stored in ecx is listed as "A" (correct) right before the call
// to "add ecx, 1" at which point ecx somehow resets to 0 when it should be "B"

    str1 = strdup("ABC 123 779 Hello World") ;
    r = strrepl(str1, '#', &isdigit) ;
    printf("str1 = \"%s\"\n", str1) ;
    printf("%d chararcters were replaced\n", r) ;
    free(str1) ;
    return 0;
}
```

And my .asm file:

```
; File: strrepl.asm
; Implements a C function with the prototype:
;
;   int strrepl(char *str, int c, int (* isinsubset) (int c) ) ;
;
; 
; Result: chars in string are replaced with the replacement character and string is returned.

    SECTION .text
    global  strrepl


_strrepl:   nop
strrepl:
    push    ebp         ; set up stack frame
    mov ebp, esp

    push    esi         ; save registers
    push    ebx
    xor eax, eax
    mov ecx, [ebp + 8]      ;load string (char array) into ecx
    jecxz   end         ;jump if [ecx] is zero
    mov esi, [ebp + 12]     ;move the replacement character into esi
    mov edx, [ebp + 16]     ;move function pointer into edx
    xor bl, bl          ;bl will be our counter


firstLoop:
    add bl, 1           ;inc bl would work too
    add ecx, 1
    mov eax, [ecx]  
    cmp eax, 0
    jz  end
    push    eax         ; parameter for (*isinsubset)
    ;BREAK
    call    edx         ; execute (*isinsubset)

    add esp, 4          ; "pop off" the parameter
    mov ebx, eax        ; store return value




end:
    pop ebx         ; restore registers
    pop esi
    mov esp, ebp        ; take down stack frame
    pop ebp
    ret
```

When running this through gdb and putting a breakpoint at ;BREAK, it segfaults after I take a step to the call command with the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0081320f in isdigit () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

isdigit is part of the standard c library that i have included in my c file, so I am not sure what to make of this.

Edit: I have edited my firstLoop and included a secondLoop which should replace any digits with "#", however it seems to replace the entire array.

```
firstLoop:

    xor eax, eax

    mov edi, [ecx]
    cmp edi, 0
    jz  end

    mov edi, ecx        ; save array


    movzx   eax, byte [ecx]     ;load single byte into eax  
    mov ebp, edx        ; save function pointer
    push    eax         ; parameter for (*isinsubset)           
    call    edx         ; execute (*isinsubset)

    ;cmp    eax, 0
    ;jne    end

    mov ecx, edi        ; restore array
    cmp eax, 0
    jne secondLoop  
    mov edx, ebp        ; restore function pointer
    add esp, 4          ; "pop off" the parameter
    mov ebx, eax        ; store return value
    add ecx, 1
    jmp firstLoop

secondLoop:
    mov [ecx], esi
    mov edx, ebp
    add esp, 4
    mov ebx, eax
    add ecx, 1
    jmp     firstLoop
```

Using gdb, when the code gets to secondloop, everything is correct. ecx is showing as "1" which is the first digit in the string that was passed in from the .c file. Esi is displaying as "#" as it should be. However, after I do mov [ecx], esi it seems to fall apart. ecx is displaying as "#" as it should at this point, but once I increment by 1 to get to the next character in the array, it is listed as "/000" with display. Every character after the 1 is replaced with "#" is listed as "/000" with display. Before I had the secondLoop trying to replace the characters with "#", I just had firstLoop looping with it self to see if it could make it through the entire array without crashing. It did, and after each increment ecx was displaying as the correct character. I am not sure why doing mov [ecx], esi would have set the rest of ecx to null.

Comment: If that had assembled, it still wouldn't have worked: `cl` is the low byte of `ecx`, so you'd have lost that byte. You haven't mentioned `edi`, it might be free.

Comment: cl is an 8-bit register, eax is a 32-bit register.  You can move "al" or "ah" into cl; you can move eax into ecx ... but you can't move eax into cl.

Comment: I decided to go with ebx since I am going to restore the register when I finish anyway, and I ended up segfaulting before it could get to that point in the code. I have edited my question to reflect this

Comment: Did i miss a jump to firstLoop somewhere (as i expect it)?

Comment: firstloop just executes right after the final xor command in strrepl. However I have edited my post to include a stack trace after fixing another issue which was ecx getting replaced with 0 with the calls to add bl, 1.

Comment: Sorry for the large amounts of edits, I realized I was displaying the wrong register, the edited post above is now correct.

Comment: @user2357446: There is a lot wrong with this code. I think you need to get a better understanding of the way the CPU works.

Comment: @user2357446: keep in mind that by using `display/c` you're not getting the full value of `eax`.  The `/c` format tells `display` to only output the lowest byte of `eax`.

Comment: `mov [ecx], esi` has the same problem you initially had - it's writing the four bytes in `esi` to the string instead of the single byte you want written. You'll need to do something like `mov eax, esi;mov [ecx], al`

Answer (score 1):

In your `firstLoop:` you're loading characters from the string using:

```
mov eax, [ecx]
```

which is loading 4 bytes at a tie instead of a single byte.  So the `int` that you're passing to `isdigit()` is likely to by far out of range for it to handle (it probably uses a simple table lookup).

You can load a single byte using the following Intel asm syntax:

```
movzx eax, byte ptr [ecx]
```

A few other things:

- it will also have the effect that it probably wouldn't detect the end of the string properly since the null terminator might not be followed by three other zero bytes.
- I'm not sure why you increment `ecx` before processing the first character in the string
- the assembly code you posted doesn't appear to actually loop over the string

Comment: So in order to not load all 4 bytes of the character, would I simply mov eax, [ecx-3] or something similar? As for incrementing ecx and not looping yet, I simply wanted to get my code to run through one time before configuring it to actually loop through the whole string. I also caught that I am not processing A, which I fixed. However, the same error remains in that I need to figure out how to not pass all 4 bytes to isdigit().

Comment: Upon further examination, since chars are loaded with 4 bytes, I need to make sure the top 24 bits of the 4-byte value are zeroed before being passed. However I only know of commands to clear the top 16,32, and 64 bits. Not 24.

Comment: Just tried the code on my PC using DevSutdio 2010 and the in the debug build, the isdigit function is asserting due to the input being out of range - does gcc have the same check?

Comment: I am not sure, but I talked to a professor briefly and my issue seems to be the following: When you pass a character to isdigit(), isxdigit() or isvowel, it is being passed as a 4-byte int. Make sure that the top 24 bits of the 4-byte value are zeroed out before you push it onto the stack. If calling isdigit() or isxdigit() causes a seg fault, use gdb to check the entire 32-bits on the stack before the CALL instruction. I am now trying to figure out what combination of xor, or, etc commands I can use to zero out the last 24 bits of the register before pushing it to the stack, but no luck.

Comment: @rajraj: `isdigit()` probably does a lookup in a table of attribute bits use by all the `isxxx()` functions - without range checking the argument. On my Linux box it certainly does.

Comment: @user2357446: see my update to the question for how to load a single byte into `eax`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I see, I could perhaps load the current [ecx] into a different free register and check if that is the null terminator before loading the first byte into eax. I will try that and get back to you. Thanks for all your help so far :)

Comment: @MichaelBurr movzx eax, byte ptr [ecx] results in strrepl.asm:30: error: comma or end of line expected

Comment: how are you assembling/compiling `strrepl.asm`?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Apologies, I did some research and found out that it also accepts eax, byte [ecx] as well. When making this change the call to the function executes without a segfault and eax is changed to the return value (0 in this case for "B"). Now I just need to make it loop through and change all of the characters that are digits to the given replacement character. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Now it seems that ecx is being changed after the function call. gdb shows ecx as "B" before the function call, and right after it is changed to '|'. I have tried pushing-popping ecx before and after the call, but that just results in more segfaults.

Answer (score 0):

I've put some comments into your code:-

```
  ; this is OK: setting up the stack frame and saving important register
  ; on Win32, the registers that need saving are: esi, edi and ebx
  ; the rest can be used without needing to preserve them
  push    ebp
  mov ebp, esp
  push    esi
  push    ebx

  xor eax, eax
  mov ecx, [ebp + 8]

  ; you said that this checked [ecx] for zero, but I think you've just written
  ; that wrong, this checks the value of ecx for zero, the [reg] form usually indicates
  ; the value at the address defined by reg
  ; so this is effectively doing a null pointer check (which is good)
  jecxz   end

  mov esi, [ebp + 12]
  mov edx, [ebp + 16]
  xor bl, bl

firstLoop:
  add bl, 1
  ; you increment ecx before loading the first character, this means
  ; that the function ignores the first character of the string
  ; and will therefore produce an incorrect result if the string
  ; starts with a character that needs replacing
  add ecx, 1
  ; characters are 8 bit, not 32 bit (mentioned in comments elsewhere)
  mov eax, [ecx]  
  cmp eax, 0
  jz  end
  push    eax
  ; possibly segfaults due to character out of range
  ; also, as mentioned elsewhere, the function you call here must conform to the 
  ; the standard calling convention of the system (e.g, preserve esi, edi and ebx for
  ; Win32 systems), so eax, ecx and edx can change, so next time you call
  ; [edx] it might be referencing random memory
  ; either save edx on the stack (push before pushing parameters, pop after add esp)
  ; or just load edx with [ebp+16] here instead of at the start
  call    edx

  add esp, 4
  mov ebx, eax

  ; more functionality required here!



end:
  ; restore important values, etc
  pop ebx
  pop esi
  mov esp, ebp
  pop ebp
  ; the result of the function should be in eax, but that's not set up properly yet
  ret
```

Comments on your inner loop:-

```
firstLoop:

    xor eax, eax

    ; you're loading a 32 bit value and checking for zero,
    ; strings are terminated with a null character, an 8 bit value,
    ; not a 32 bit value, so you're reading past the end of the string
    ; so this is unlikely to correctly test the end of string

    mov edi, [ecx]
    cmp edi, 0
    jz  end

    mov edi, ecx        ; save array


    movzx   eax, byte [ecx]     ;load single byte into eax  
    ; you need to keep ebp! its value must be saved (at the end, 
    ; you do a mov esp,ebp)
    mov ebp, edx        ; save function pointer
    push    eax         ; parameter for (*isinsubset)           
    call    edx         ; execute (*isinsubset)

    mov ecx, edi        ; restore array
    cmp eax, 0
    jne secondLoop  
    mov edx, ebp        ; restore function pointer
    add esp, 4          ; "pop off" the parameter
    mov ebx, eax        ; store return value
    add ecx, 1
    jmp firstLoop

secondLoop:
    ; again, your accessing the string using a 32 bit value, not an 8 bit value
    ; so you're replacing the matched character and the three next characters
    ; with the new value
    ; the upper 24 bits are probably zero so the loop will terminate on the
    ; next character
    ; also, the function seems to be returning a count of characters replaced,
    ; but you're not recording the fact that characters have been replaced
    mov [ecx], esi
    mov edx, ebp
    add esp, 4
    mov ebx, eax
    add ecx, 1
    jmp     firstLoop
```

You do seem to be having trouble with the way the memory works, you are getting confused between 8 bit and 32 bit memory access.

Comment: See my edits, I fixed the iteration issues and I added a secondLoop that actually does the replacing of the characters with the provided replacement character (in this case, "#") however it seems to be replacing the first digit with "#" and setting the rest of the array to null.

Comment: @user2357446: I've included your new code and added some comments.

Comment: Commenting on accessing 32 bit values vs 8 bit values, you are saying that instead of mov edi, [ecx] it would be movzx edi, byte [ecx]? If thats the case, how would I apply this to secondLoop? esi is not stored as a character array. It is passed in as an int, so when I try to use "byte esi" it obviously throws errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2357446: The parameter is only defined as an int because it was originally a more optimal way to pass the value. In assembler, it's up to you to decide how the memory is organised, so a char stored as an int in C does not need to read as an int, you can just read the lower 8 bits and ignore the rest. Unfortunately, there is no reverse movzx (i.e. store 32bits in to 8bit address). You can only write an 8 bit value to memory from an 8 bit register. So using esi is not going to work. 'mov eax,[ebp+12] ; mov [edi],al' will work.

Comment: Ah I see, so either the first option you mention or simply loading in with mov al, [ebp+12]. Obviously the first option you mentioned is more streamlined, but I think both will work. A sample implementation is tricky though, because your example of "mov eax, [ebp+12] would replace all of eax with whatever is stored in [ebp+12] instead of replacing an individual character, no? I say this because normally you would access a single character in ecx with square brackets

Comment: @user2357446: `mov byte [ecx], [epb+12]` is not a valid addressing mode you must have a load instruction followed by a store.

Comment: Well, I tried doing mov al, [ebp + 12], and al was displaying as "/000" whereas mov esi, [ebp + 12] displayed correctly as "#". Ill try the second option you suggested

Comment: Edit: Wow, I cant believe that went over my head, I read that mov eax,[ebp+12] ; mov [edi],al as two different suggestions, not one. My mistake. That should work since al is just the first 8 bits of eax. Ill give it a shot